# Blurring app screen in switch mode on iOS

Tags: ios, onblur

I want to use blurring in my iOS app when it switch. Like PayPal and some other financial app where need to hide information. But I can't find any information or hint about this feature.

For example PayPal realization: http://40.media.tumblr.com/0334b065e28dfe2e325d32822d87246b/tumblr_mwcl35TZIt1qea4hso1_1280.jpg

Comment: You mean when you app goes to the background (is no longer active)? Did you search for duplicates?

Comment: Yes, application in background, but we can see screen this app on multitask panel. I need blur this screen to hide private information.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to add the following code to your `applicationWillResignActive` function

```
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = window!.frame
    blurEffectView.tag = 221122

    self.window?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Then in  your `applicationDidBecomeActive`, use the line

```
self.window?.viewWithTag(221122)?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Thanks, it work! But after app all time have blur, even foreground. How I can abort blur after application become active? (I know it can be simple, but doesnt work. I use obj-c)

Comment: @SulTan updated code. it's objC would be `[[self.window viewWithTag:221122] removeFromSuperview]`

Comment: All done, thanks! A small addition: `[[self.window viewWithTag:221122] removeFromSuperview]` need put in `applicationDidBecomeActive` too

Comment: Notice that applicationWillEnterForeground is not called when the control center or notification center is shown then dismissed (and a couple of other events). Might consider moving the removeFromSuperView in applicationDidBecomeActive